# textView not showing up in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

So I'm trying to create a list fragment with a textview on top of the list items, but I can't get the textview to show up.

Here is my code for the list fragment

```
public class VarsFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<VarData> VarList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    VarList = AllVars.get(getActivity()).getAllVars();
    VarAdapter varAdapter = new VarAdapter(VarList);
    setListAdapter(varAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vars, container, false);
    TextView Header = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.VarHeader);
    Header.setText("Variables");
    return rootView;
}

private class VarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VarData> {
    public VarAdapter(ArrayList<VarData> variables) {
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, variables);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        VarData varData = getItem(position);
        TextView varNameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.varstv1);
        varNameTextView.setText(varData.getVarName());
        TextView varValueTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.varstv2);
        varValueTextView.setText(varData.getVarValue());
        ImageView editIndicator = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editable_indicator);
        if (varData.isEditable())
        {
            editIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            editIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

public static VarsFragment newInstance(String text) {

    VarsFragment f = new VarsFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
```

And here is the code for the xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity$VarsFragment"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#ffff8800">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/VarHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

When I run my app, my list shows up, but my textview remains empty instead of showing the header "Variables".

Thanks for any help

edit:
Don't I just add

```
TextView Header;
```

at the top and

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.VarHeader);
    Header.setText("Variables");
    Header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: It's interesting. I may have missed something but I don't see an error in your code. Are you sure you are loading the correct layout or instantiating the correct `Fragment`? Is the `TextView` present in the layout? I mean does it take up space above the `ListView`? If not you can confirm that it is at least present in the layout by taking your device and going to Settings -> Developer Options and checking "Show layout bounds" in the section "Drawing". If you return to your app afterwards you should see a square around the `TextView` making it visible even without text or background color.

Comment: I see the TextView in the layout (It takes up space above the ListView and I see a box when editing the xml)

I'm confused on this too since I also don't see an error, but it's not working.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Try to clear the project and recompile everything. You can also restart Eclipse. Also try to move your code around a little. Save the `TextView` in a global variable and set the text in `onViewCreated`.

Comment: I'm using android studio.

I just tried setting the text in onViewCreated, but it didn't work and caused my list to not show up.

Comment: What? That does not make any sense. You must be doing something wrong somewhere but it is not in your code.

Comment: Wait, don't I just add (code did not look well on comment, added an edit above)

Comment: I don't see any edit of your question besides the one by Libin one hour ago.

Comment: Sorry about that, was editting it when you replied to me

Comment: And what is your question about the code you just edited in?

Comment: You said I was doing something wrong so I just wanted to make sure I was writing the onViewCreated correctly

Comment: Yeah that's all fine, I don't understand why you get those errors. It should work, there must be something else wrong. I tested the code you posted, it works perfectly. The error is not in the code.

Comment: That's weird then. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case the the textview was hidden because of the action bar. I added "paddingTop" to my fragments layout to fix this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/action_bar_height"   
    tools:context="my frag context">
```

action_bar_height = 56dp(Portrait) or 48dp(Landscape)